# Proof a set is bounded or not

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Proof set $V=\{(x,y): x+y \leq 1\}$ is bounded or not.

I tried to use the definition of , if there exists a $m$ s.t.$\|(x,y)\|$=<$m$ then the set V will be bounded.

I tried to start of with $\|(x,y)\|^2$=$x^2+y^2$ but this expression can never be smaller than $x+y$ so i concluded that the bound doesnt exist. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try to graph x+y <= 1

Comment: I saw that it was just a line accepting every combination of x en y which makes it =<1, i thought it is unbounded

Comment: yes it is unb .

Comment: But i was wondering how to proof it formally. I tried to use the definition but i failed i guess

Comment: think of that V cannot be squeezed in any ball of any center and any radius.. try to do it

Comment: For every positive integer $n$, if $x=n$, then you can have $y=-n$, such that $(x,y) \in V$. Now see if you can complete the argument.

Comment: This is how the argument could go: I (or the universe, or the god of arbitrariness) will give you a large number $M$. Now find a point where the sum of the $x$ and $y$ coordinates is less than $1$ (for instance, negative), but the distance to the origin is larger than $M$.

Comment: @Arthur which origin do you mean?

Comment: @AnuragA can you tell me from where i stopped $x^2+y^2$ to complete the proof , what am i missing i used the definition but i am stuck at this step should i just say $x^2+y^2$=>x+y thus the set is unbounded?

Comment: I mean the origin $(0,0)$.

Comment: @Arthur can you look at my last comment? How did i do it?

Comment: @Mark to show a set is unbounded, usually one uses a proof by contradiction. So assume the set is bounded by a bound $M$, i.e. you are assuming that $x^2+y^2 \leq M$ For all $(x,y) \in V$. Now based on the idea I have suggested pick an integer $K >M$, then $(x,y)=(K,-K) \in V$ but $x^2+y^2=2K^2> M$, hence our assumption of boundedness is false.

Comment: @Mark Your original proof can't be completed because it starts off on the wrong track. You can't prove your desired statement by manipulating universally valid inequalities. You **must choose** points from **the given set** $V$ that exceed arbitrarily large bounds. See Arthur's comment, Anurag A's comment, and DeepSea's answer for details.

Comment: I will try now, but i am thinking now should we already know by forehand that the set V is already unbounded and then proof that it is unbounded? Or should we know that it is unbounded when we start our proof writing? And then all of  sudden we know that it will be unbounded? So should we always check by forehand?

Comment: @AnuragA yes but can we say by forehand that $K$ there exists a $K$ > $M$? How do we know that such a $K$ exists? Or is it thst we know already that the function is unbounded because i sketch it thus thats why we assume a $K$ must exists which is greater than $M$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose on the contrary that $V$ is bounded, then there exists $m>0$ such that for each $(x,y)$ in $V$, $\| (x,y) \|\leq m.$

Let $x= -2m$ and $y=0$.

We have $x+y=-2m<0<1$, hence $(x,y) \in V$.

Notice that $\|(x,y)\|=\sqrt{(-2m)^2+0^2}=2m >m$ which is a contradiction.

Hence $V$ is unbounded.

Remark:
You need not choose the point to be $(-2m, 0)$, $(0,-2m)$ works too. In fact, the whole third quadrant, $Q_3$ is a subset of $V$ and a quadrant is unbounded. You can pick any point on the third quadrant of which its distance from the origin is more than $m$ to achieve similar proof. That is any points that satisfy $(a,b)$, $a<0$, $b<0$, $a^2+b^2 > m^2$.

**A linear algebra approach**

If you are familiar with linear algebra, especially with the concept of orthogonality, let's solve a bigger problem rather than just studying the set $V$.

**Claim** Let $a \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $b \in \mathbb{R}$,$V_{a,b} = \{ a^Tz \leq b: z \in \mathbb{R}^2\}$, is either empty or unbounded.

**Proof**

Suppose $V_{a,b}$ is non-empty, let $p \in V_{a,b}$. That is $a^Tp \leq b$

We know that $\exists d \in \mathbb{R}^2, d \neq 0, a^Td=0$.

We can easily verify that  $\forall \epsilon >0$,$a^T(p+\epsilon d) \leq b.$ That is $p+\epsilon d \in V_{a,b}$

$\|p+\epsilon d\|^2=(p+\epsilon d)^T(p+\epsilon d)=\|p\|^2+2\epsilon p^Td+\epsilon^2\|d\|^2$ which is just a quadratic equation in $\epsilon$.

$$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow \infty}\| p+\epsilon d\|^2=\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow \infty}(\|p\|^2+2\epsilon p^Td+\epsilon^2\|d\|^2)=\infty$$

Hence $V_{a,b}$ is unbounded. $\blacksquare$

Note that there is nothing special about $\mathbb{R}^2$, the argument works for $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $n \geq 2$.

If you know this result, for your particular question, our $a=(1,1)^T$, $b=1$. you just have to verify that it is non-empty, $(0,0)$ is in $V$ and you are done.

Suppose you want to construct a point explicitly as a counter example. You just have to first, find a point in $V$, call it $p$, find a vector $d$ such that $d^Ta=0$, $d \neq 0$, and solve a quadratic inequality such that $\|p\|^2+2\epsilon p^Td+\epsilon^2\|d\|^2 \geq m^2$ and construct $p+\epsilon d$.

**Alternative proof**

What happens when $a=0$? If the statement $0 \leq b$ is true, $V_{0,b}=\mathbb{R}^n$. If the statement $0 \leq b$ is false, $V_{0,b} = \emptyset$

What happens if $a \neq 0$? Let $z=-ka$, where $k \geq \max\left( \frac{-b}{\|a\|^2},\frac{\sqrt2m}{\|a\|}\right).$

$$a^Tz=a^T(-ak)=-\|a\|^2k \leq -\|a\|^2\left( \frac{-b}{\|a\|^2}\right)=b$$

Hence, $z \in V_{a,b}$.

Also, $\|z\|^2 = k^2 \|a\|^2 \geq \|a\|^2 \left( \frac{2m^2}{\|a\|^2}\right) =2m^2 > m^2$

Comment: How did you ever choose -2m?

Comment: We need $x+y \leq 1$ and $x^2+y^2>m^2$. I set $y=0$ and that reduces the problem to $x \leq 1$ and $|x| > m$. I can pick $x$ to be negative and the first criterio is satisfied and the second inequality becomes $-x > m$ which is equivalent to $x < -m$. In particular, $x=-2m$ is a possible choice.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rw71tnvujc   You can pick any point that is outside the blue circle and inside the shaded region.

Comment: Hmmm alrigt but can you look at what i said here :@AnuragA yes but can we say by forehand that $K$ there exists a $K$ > $M$? How do we know that such a $K$ exists? Or is it thst we know already that the function is unbounded because i sketch it thus thats why we assume a $K$ must exists which is greater than $M$? It this a correct way of proof formally?

Comment: one skill in maths is to conjecture and verify if a statement is true. For this case, the reason could be simply the line $y=-x$ falls entirely in the shaded region.  We can pick points that are on the line that are far away from origin.  You do not have to observe the same thing. For instance, you can observe that the $x$-axis when $x$ is negative fall inside the region and look for points of the form of $(-K,0)$ instead. You might also observe that $y=x$ where $x \leq 0$ fall inside the region and choose points of the form of $(-K,-K)$ instead.

Comment: thank you for your answer!!!

Comment: additional exercise if you would like : check whether $\{ (x, y): x+y = 1\}$ is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

For each $m > 0$, you can choose $x = 2m, y = 1-2m$, and $||(x,y)|| = \sqrt{4m^2+(1-2m)^2}>m$, this shows the set is unbounded. The argument is rather simple, but since you are new so it takes times to get used to.

Comment: Why  is it that i could not think of that myself??

Comment: Its a very hard proof you used, i rather want to proceed where i could not proceed further and was stuck

Comment: Or just $x=-2m,y=0$, and $\|(x,y)\|=2m$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=0$ and the constraint simplifies to $x\le1$. Does that imply $|x|\le m$ ?